# What GPIO pins are not multiplexed with essential components onboard?

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, pi-4

I am in need a lot of chip select pins for my circuit (8 pins) and I am worried about pins being multiplexed which might suddenly pull high/low mid operation. Ill only be using the HDMI port, Ethernet, and USB of the Raspberry Pi 3B+/4. So, if there are GPIO pins that are multiplexed for those devices I would like to know.

What GPIO should I look out for? are the [sdio](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/sdio) pins shared with the actual SD card or is this for another external SD card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the GPIO pins are *'multiplexed'* in the sense you mean. In other words, some of the GPIO pins have **alternate functions**, but these are functions that you maintain control of in your configuration, and in your code. You do not need to worry about ***the system*** commandeering a GPIO pin for some other purpose.

There are many sources of detailed information about the GPIO pins available online - [here's one I like](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/raspberry-pi-gpio-pinout,6122.html) - and so I'll not repeat that here.

In the interest of adhering to *absolute truth*, I should add this caveat to my answer: the raspberry pi is **not** an open-source system. There are many hardware details that remain unpublished after all of these years, and the reaspberry pi firmware is not open source. The only point I am making here is that no one without access to those closed sources can give an absolute answer to your question. I can only tell you that there are no **recognized** uses for GPIO pins on the RPi - i.e. if you are building a *life-support* system, you'd be considered reckless if you used an RPi for that. For hobby usage, yeah - no multiplexing on GPIO pins. :)

Comment: That is good to hear, what community recognizes is good enough for me. And not to worry im not building a life-support system :D. Thank you for the answer good sir.

Answer (score 1):

No pins are "multiplexed" with ANYTHING.

Pins 27,28 (GPIO0,1) are reserved for HATs.